# Change of variable for logistic distribution to loglogistic - where do I go wrong?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, logistic-distribution

Similar to what I described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408398/how-should-i-solve-the-problem-the-pdf-of-x-is-fx-what-is-the-pdf-of-g) I would like to make the following change of variable $$Y := \exp( \eta + \sigma e ), \sigma>0 $$ where $e$ has the standard logistic density $f_E(e) = \exp(e)/(1+\exp(e))^2$. Note that this equation is invariant to a change of $\exp(e)$ by $\exp(-e)$ in denominator and numerator.

Density of $Y$, i.e. $f_Y(y)$, should be log-logistic. To derive this I make a change of variables with $$g(y) = \exp( \eta + \sigma y )$$ so that $$g^{-1}(y) = (\ln(y)-\eta)/\sigma.$$ Furthermore we have $$\frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) = (y\sigma)^{-1}. $$ Then applying $$f_Y(y)=f_E(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|$$
we find $$f_Y(y)= \frac{\exp( (\ln(y) - \eta)/\sigma )}{(1+\exp( (\ln(y) - \eta)/\sigma ))^2}(y\sigma)^{-1}.$$
Now the density of the log-logistic distribution is given by $$f_Y(y)= \frac{y^{\gamma-1} \lambda^\gamma \gamma}{(1+(y\lambda)^\gamma)^2},$$
if we re-apramerterize $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sigma }$ and $\lambda=\exp{-\eta}$. However, from simulations I find that this is false and I have to use $\lambda=\exp{\eta}$ instead. I paste the code to reproduce this result below. Where do I go wrong?

```
library(actuar)
# Hard coded random draw from the logistic distribution
qlog = function(p) log(p)-log(1-p)
rlog = function(n){
  u = runif(n)
  qlog(u)
}

# Sample some data
n = 10^6
eta = 2
sig = 1/3
y = exp( eta + sig * rlog(n))

# Make reparametrization
gamma = 1/ sig
lambda1 = exp(-eta) #what I find in my derivation, red curve
lambda2 = exp(eta) # What seems to be correct
#

# Plot densities
plot(density(y, from=0, to = 50), xlim=c(0,50))
curve(dllogis(x, shape = gamma, scale= lambda1 ) , add=T, col=2)
curve(dllogis(x, shape = gamma, scale= lambda2 ) , add=T, col=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the log-logistic density defined by : 
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{y^{\gamma−1}\lambda^\gamma\gamma}{{ (1 + (\lambda y)^\gamma)}^2},$$
$\lambda$ corresponds to a rate parameter, whereas in your call of the function:

`dllogis(x, shape = gamma, scale= lambda1 )`

you pass it as a scale. there is a inverse relation between the two, so you should call `dllogis(x, shape = gamma, scale= 1 / lambda1 )`. I think your derivation is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I had misread the help file. Indeed scale $s = 1/\lambda = exp(\eta)$. Alternatively I can pass `rate=lambda1` directly.